# how to add external shadow images in birt reports

Tags: java, report, birt

I have a report, where I am displaying image(dynamic image name) based on the column value,  how to set  shadow  images ,if  images is null in database then  display shadow images in birt report which is located resources

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have two images and manage their visibility based on the value of column. ie if there is null in database then set visibility of shadow image is true and other one is false.
This is how you can set visibility of particular widget.
[image]